# Pull multiple Git repositories at once Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have several projects in Netbeans all with their respective Git repository. With the SVN plugin I was able to get the changes, update and commit for all the projects at once.

I want to know if there is a way in Netbeans to do that:

- fetch multiple repositories at once (on current branch),
- pull multiple repositories at once (on current branch),
- commit/push on multiple repositories at once (on current branch),
- bonus: create branch with the same name on multiple repositories at once,
- bonus 2: commit and push in one operation.

Right now I have to update each project one after the other and it is taking quite the time...

Thank you.

Comment: Please note that "pull" is just a shortcut for "fetch && merge"

Comment: Also, when you say "multiple repositories" do you mean multiple _remotes_?

Comment: Yes I mean multiple remotes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations this may help

Comment: Sorry by multiple remotes I meant a remote by project. Each project has one remote, but I have several projects.

Answer (score 0):

Press "Ctrl", select all the projects you want to pull/fetch/push and then click on the button which will launch the command you need.